# Haskell: Why doesn't my evaluation function for arithmetic get executed while data evaluation gets executed?

Tags: parsing, haskell, compiler-construction

I'm writing a simple language but have encountered a problem in that arithmetic expressions don't expect their operators despite the fact they're defined in the language. I have since gone back to express my program more simply. At the moment the only complicated expression that I have is arithmetic. I can parse integers, strings, booleans, and, lists. It can recognise expressions such as "5 Add 5" but only in the form of a list, "[5 Add 5]".

I suspect it doesn't parse when it's not in a list due to how atoms are parsed. An atom parser parses booleans and then an arbitrary atom. If the arithmetic expression is placed into a string, it will also be parsed properly.

I'm not sure why it's not evaluating correctly though. I have an evaluation function that deals with arithmetic expressions but it does not work when I try to give it arguments through the command line. When I load it into GHCI, I can use it perfectly so I know the arithmetic evaluation function works, but I'm failing to see why it's not evaluating when I give it command line arguments. Any arithmetic expression just results in the expression itself, not the value that should be returned.

The only reason I can think of is that when the expression is parsed, it isn't parsed as an arithmetic expression but instead it's parsed as a list or a string.

```
data HenryVal = Integer Integer
              | Bool Bool
              | Atom String
              | String String 
              | List [HenryVal]
              | ABinOp ABinOp
              | Ad HenryVal HenryVal
              | ABinary ABinOp HenryVal HenryVal

data ABinOp = Add
            | Subtract
            | Multiply
            | Divide
             deriving (Show)

evalABinOp :: HenryVal -> ABinOp -> HenryVal -> HenryVal
evalABinOp (Integer a) Add (Integer b) = Integer (a +b)
evalABinOp (Integer a) Multiply (Integer b) = Integer (a * b)
evalABinOp (Integer a) Divide (Integer b) = Integer (a `div` b)
evalABinOp (Integer a) Subtract (Integer b) = Integer (a - b) 

eval :: HenryVal -> HenryVal
eval val@(Atom _) = val
eval val@(String _) = val
eval val@(Integer _) = val
eval val@(Bool _) = val
eval (List [Atom "quote", val]) = val
eval val@(List _) = val
eval (ABinary op x y) = evalABinOp (eval x) op (eval y)

spaces :: Parser ()
spaces = skipMany1 space

parseString :: Parser HenryVal
parseString = do
    char '"'
    x <- many (noneOf "\"")
    char '"'
    return $ String x

parseList :: Parser HenryVal
parseList = liftM List $ sepBy parseExpr spaces

parseNumber :: Parser HenryVal
parseNumber = liftM (Integer . read) $ many1 digit

parseAtom :: Parser HenryVal
parseAtom = do 
              first <- letter
              rest <- many (letter <|> digit)
              let atom = first:rest
              return $ case atom of 
                         "True" -> Bool True
                         "False" -> Bool False
                         _ -> Atom atom

parseExpr :: Parser HenryVal   
parseExpr =  parseNumber <|>
             parseAtom   <|>
             parseString <|>
             do
                 _ <- char '['
                 x <- try parseList
                 _ <- char ']'
                 return x

readExpr :: String -> HenryVal
readExpr input = case parse parseExpr "Henry" input of
    Left error -> String $ "No Match: " ++ show error
    Right val -> val

main :: IO ()
main = getArgs >>= print . eval . readExpr . head
```

Comment: Can you provide an expression that fails?

Comment: Nothing fails per se. If I were to type "[4 Add 4]", I am given a list containing 4 Add 4. It's parsed, but it's not evaluated.

Comment: Where are you typing this?

Comment: @thatotherguy I compile the program on the command line with "stack ghc foo.hs". Then I execute it with "./foo EXPRESSION" if that makes any sense.

Comment: Ok. Then you presumably have a main method that uses `getArgs` or similar to get that expression as a string. What do you do with that `String` to turn it into a `HenryVal`?

Comment: @thatotherguy I added the code in an edit. If I'm understanding you correctly, my main function gets the arguments with getArgs, then parses it through readExpr and evaluates each part of it with eval.

Comment: So you're writing your own parser with Parsec or similar. It sounds like `eval` is fine, but that the parsing functions you wrote is misinterpreting the input due to bugs in your code. For example, if your parser takes in `"[4 Add 4]"` and incorrectly outputs `String "4 Add 4"` instead of `List [ABinary Add (Integer 4) (Integer 4)]`, then you might see things similar to what you're seeing. You can remove the `eval` to show the unevaluated output of your parser and make sure it's correct.

Comment: @thatotherguy So if I'm understanding you correctly, the eval function isn't exhaustive in that it doesn't account for the case in which a list is returned containing [ABinary ABinOp Val1 Val2] ?

Comment: @4castle I added it there

Comment: @JiangShi My point is that `eval` is probably fine and that the bug you're seeing is in `readExpr`. You say things are working perfectly in `ghci`. What do you enter in `ghci` that works perfectly, and what is the output?

Comment: @thatotherguy  In `ghci` I enter `eval $ evalABinOp (Integer 4) Add (Integer 4)` and it gives me 8. It's really interesting to hear the bug is in `readExpr`. I have a feeling that bug is due to the fact that it gives a value which in my case is everything but the arithmetic expression because the arithmetic expression is built up out of multiple values and `readExpr` is only expecting a single value.

Comment: That is equivalent to `eval $ ABinary Add (Integer 4) (Integer 4)`, and works perfectly (note that `ghci` does not invoke `readExpr` here, so it does not show that `readExpr` works). If you invoke it in ghci with `eval $ readExpr "4 Add 4"` then you get the wrong result in ghci as well. If `readExpr "4 Add 4"` returned `ABinary Add (Integer 4) (Integer 4)` then everything would work, but it instead returns `Integer 4` so you get the wrong result. Therefore you should stop looking at `eval` and instead fix `readExpr`

Comment: @thatotherguy Is it strictly an issue with `readExpr` or does the problem persist into other areas of the code? It seems to me that the `readExpr` error would be due to expecting a single value but the arithmetic expression is multiple values. Either that or it's a case of not having a parser for arithmetic expressions.

Comment: The reason why `4 Add 4` fails is because parsing returns the wrong result, exactly because you don't have a parser for expressions with binary operators. You would fix it by adding and modifying `parse[...]` functions, and finally verify that it parses correctly by calling `readExpr "4 Add 4"` in ghci and making sure it outputs `ABinary Add (Integer 4) (Integer 4)`

Comment: @thatotherguy that clears everything up! I know how to proceed now. Thank you!